# Autosar Network Management SWS 4.2.2. - Partial networking

Tags: autosar

In Autosar NM 4.2.2 **NM PDU Filter Algorithm**, 
What is significance of **CanNmPnFilterMaskByte** . I understood that it is used to Mask(AND) with incoming NM PDU with Partial Network info and decide to participate in communication or not. But please explain how exactly it works in brief.

Answer (score 7):

You are actually talking about **P**artial **N**etworking. So, if certain functional clusters are not needed anymore, they can go to sleep and save power.

ECUs supporting PN check all NmPdus for the PartialNetworkingInfo (PNI, where each bit represents a functional cluster status) in the NmPdus UserData.

The PnFilterMask actually filters out any irrelevant PNI info, the ECU is not interested in at all (because the ECU does not contribute in any way to these functions). If after applying the filter, everything is 0, the NmPdu is discarded, and does therefore not cause a restart of the Nm-Timeout Timer. Which brings actually the Nm into the Go-to-sleep phase, even though, NmPdus are still transmitted.

By ECU, also consider Gateways.

*Update how to determine the mask*

As described above, each bit represents a function.

```
Bit0 : Func0
..
Bit7: Func7
```

The OEM would now have to check, which ECUs in the Vehicle are necessary for which functions (also at certain state) required or not, and how to layout the vehicle networks.

Here are some function examples, and ECUs required excluding gateways:

- ACC : 1 radar sensor front
- EBA : 1 camera + 1..n radar sensor front
- ParkDistanceControl (PDC): 4 Front- + 4 Rear Sensors + Visualization in Dashboard
- Backup Camera: 1 Camera + Visualization ECU (the lines which tell according to steering angle / speed where the vehicle would move within the camera picture)
- Blind Spot Detection (BSD) / LaneChangeAssist (LCA): 2 Radar sensors in the rear + MirrorLed Control and Buzzer Control ECU
- Rear Cross Traffic Assist (RCTA) (w/ or w/o Brake + Alert): 2 Radar Sensors in the rear + MirrorLed Control and Buzzer Control ECU
- Occupant Safe Exit (warn or keep doors closed in case something approaches): 2 rear radar sensors + DoorLock ECU(s)

The next thing is, that some functions are distributed over several ECUs. 
e.g. the 2 rear radar sensors can do the whole BSD/LCA, RCTA, OSE functions, including maybe LED driver for the MirrorLEDs and a rear buzzer driver, or the send this information over CAN to a central ECU which handles the MirrorLEDs and a rear buzzer. (such short range radar sensors is, what I'm doing now for a long time, and the number of different functions grows over the years)
The camera can have some companion radar sensors (e.g. the one where ACC runs on or some short range radars) to help verify/classify image data / obejcts.

The PDC sensors are maybe also small ECUs giving out some information to a central PDC ECU, which actually handles the output to the dashboard.

So, not all of them need to be activated all the time and pull on the battery.
BSD/LCA, RCTA/B need to work while driving or parking, RCTA/B only when reverse gear is selected, BSD/LCA only with forward gear or neutral, PDC only when parking (low speed forward/reverse), Backup Camera only when reverse gear is in for parking, OSE can be active while standstill, with engine on (e.g. drop off passenger at traffic light) or without engine on (driver leaves and locks vehicle).

Now, for each of these cases, you need to know:

- which ECUs are still required for each vehicle state and functional state
- the network topology telling you, how these ECUs are connected.
  You need to consider gateway ECUs here, since they have to route certain information between multiple networks.

You would assign 1 bit of the Nm Flags per function or function cluster (e.g. BSD/LCA / RCTA = 1bit, OSE = 1bit, BackupCam / PDC (e.g. "Parking mode") = 1bit

e.g. CanNmPnInfo Flags might be defined as:

```
Bit0 : PowerTrain
Bit1 : Navi/Dashboard Cluster
Bit2 : BSD/LCA/RCTA
Bit3 : ParkingMode
Bit4 : OSE
...
Bit7 : SmartKeyAutomaticBackDoor (DoorLock with key in near to detect swipe/motion to automatically backdoor)
```

It may also be possible to have CL15 devices without PNI, because the functions are only active while engine is on like ACC, EBA, TrafficJamAssist ... (even BSD/LCA/RCTA could be considered like that). You could handle them maybe without CL30 + PNI.

So, you now have an assignment of function to a bit in the PNI, and you know which ECUs are required.
e.g. the radar sensors in the rear need 0x34 (Bits 2,3,4), even though, they need to be aware of, that some ECUs might not deliver infos anymore, since they are off (e.g. Speed, SteeringAngle on Powertrain turned off after CL15 off -> OSE) and this is not an error (CAN Message Timeouts).
The gateway might need some more bits in the mask, in order to keep subnetworks alive, or to actually wake up some networks and their ECUs (e.g. Remote Key waking up DoorLock ECUs)

So a gateway in the rear might have 0xFC as a mask, but a front gateway 0x03.
The backup camera might be only activated in low-speed (<20km/h) and reverse gear, to power it up but PDCs can work without reverse gear.

The PNI flags are actually usually define by the OEM, because it is a vehicle level architectural item. This can not be defined usually by a supplier.
It should be actually part of the AUTOSAR ARXML SystemDescription. (see AUTOSAR_TPS_SystemTemplate.pdf)

EcuInstance --> CanCommunicationConnector (pnc* Attributes)

Usually, the AUTOSAR Configuration Tools should support to automatically extract this information to configure CanNm / Nm and ComM (User Requests) automatically.

Sorry for the delay, but finding a example to describe it can be quite tedious,
But I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much your your answer, I was very nice explanation, I understood this concept, can you please explain how filter mask value is decided for the receiving ECU.. For example, CanNmfilterMaskByte=0x97. On what basis this value is is configured. Please explain.

Comment: Kindly help me out with the above 2nd question. Waiting for the response.

Comment: Thank you so much kesselhaus for your deep explanation, this helped me so much. Your info and explanation is so clear. Thank you again.